# onlyChild Error with React

Tags: reactjs

I'm using [rc-slider](https://react-component.github.io/slider/examples/range.html) and I'm getting the following error:

```
 Error: onlyChild must be passed a children with exactly one child.
```

I'm a bit confused because it seems like you don't pass anything inside the Rc-slider components aside from the fields required.

Code:

```
const Slider = require('rc-slider')

class PropertySlider extends Component {

   constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { 
        min:10,
        max:50,
      sliderRange: [20, 40],
    };
  }

  onSliderChange(value) {
    console.log(value);
  }

  render() {  
    return(
      <div style={{'width': '80%', 'margin': '0 auto'}}>

        <Slider 
            range 
            defaultValue={[20, 50]} 
            min={this.state.min} 
            max={this.state.max}
            onChange={this.onSliderChange}/>
      </div>
      );
    }
}
```

Comment: This error is not related to slider

Comment: I'm not entirely sure the problem lies with this component. As a debugging test, change your `render` method to be just `render() { return <div>Test</div> }`, and see if you still get the same error.

Answer (score 1):

bind you action function in constructor.

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { 
        min:10,
        max:50,
      sliderRange: [20, 40],
    };
  this.onSliderChange = this.onSliderChange.bind(this);
  }
```